# Any reliable EJS plugin/formatter/LSP for Neovim?

Tags: plugins, ejs, neovim, formatter, language-server-protocol

Does anyone know a reliable EJS plugin/formatter/LSP for Neovim?
I'm not talking about the tree-sitter parser [tree-sitter-embedded-template](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-embedded-template).

I tried using the [EJS-Lint](https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint) but it would be better if there is a specific one built for Neovim.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using EJS-Lint with [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake)